# Seeing my android application on emulator all the time

Tags: android, android-emulator

My Android application has successfully installed , but I am not sure if it ran or not.
It may have run for a short time or not at all.

How do I fix the emulator so that I can watch my application all the time?

```
[2014-01-30 12:11:22 - AndApp] Installing AndApp.apk...
[2014-01-30 12:13:12 - AndApp] Success!
[2014-01-30 12:13:13 - AndApp] Starting activity  
 com.example.AndApp.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-01-30 12:13:17 - AndApp] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.AndApp/.MainActivity }
```

Comment: Every time you need to clear the console before running it. Then you can know whats happening in background.

Comment: That seems to be only the console, have you used logcat? Enable it In Eclipse by going to Window-> Show View -> Other -> Android-> Logcat. Log can be used statically, like Log.i(String tag, String message)

Comment: You could also run in debug mode and place a breakpoint on a line which you know will run when the app starts.

Comment: Is my mistake might be   that I neither Checked Snapshot nor G host in my Avd?